# Compare versions with Git repository by hash only

Tags: git, version-control, dynamics-nav

I want to integrate Dynamics Nav (2017) with Git. One thing I don't know  how to perform in Git is how to check if object in my database has the same/older/newer version than the corresponding file in the Git repository.

Let's say I have 7500 objects in Nav. Each of them exported to the corresponding file and added to a Git repository. For each object in Nav I store the commit hash of the file that has been imported.

The problem is:

How do I check if the hash in my database is *behind*/*the same*/*from another branch* compared to *HEAD* of a specified repository? Keeping in mind that I have 7500 files and running `git log` for each of them would probably be not quite performant.

Comment: git's history is not meant to be file-oriented; that is, things like "older" or "newer" are at the commit level, and a commit is a snapshot of the entire content.  Is there a reason you can't store a *single* commit hash for the entire database, and keep everything synced to the same commit?  Then when you want to update to a different commit, you just update any files that are different between the two commits (`git diff --name-only <stored-hash> <new_commit>`)

Answer (score 0):

> How do I check if the hash in my database is behind/the same/from
>   another branch compared to HEAD of a specified repository?

You do can use `git log` to compare the given version with `HEAD`. Commands used as below:

#### To check if there has commits exist on the given version but not exist on the HEAD:

```
git log HEAD..<given hash value> --oneline
```

#### To check if there has commits exist on HEAD but not exist on the given version:

```
git log <given hash value>..HEAD --oneline
```

Then you can decide whether the given version is behind/same/ahead from `HEAD` by the output of the two commands:

- If the first command (`git log HEAD..<given hash value> --oneline`) has output, and the second command (`git log <given hash value>..HEAD --oneline`) has no output, that means the **given version ahead `HEAD`**.
- If the first command has no output, and the second command has output, that means the **given version behind `HEAD`**.
- If both first command and second command have no output, that means the **given version same as `HEAD`**.
- If both first command and second command have output, that means **the given version has some commits behind `HEAD`, and has commits ahead `HEAD`**.

Comment: That’s great. But will it work decent if I do this 7500 times in a row?

Comment: @MakSim It's ok even you have large number of files. And the two commands only list related commits not the files.